# How to display all google calendar events and add new event using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, php-5.3

I want to write one php script which can create event on google calendar and can also fetch list of event on one particular google calendar account.

I saw documentation and it is confusing and not very clear. On stack over flow there are different technic but no one explain clearly.

I have created one project into google console and i generate Public API access and i am using this code to fetch list of calendar event but i got this error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars.../google_agenda/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 110"

Also I am using updated library `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client`

And this is my code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once('google_agenda/src/Google/autoload.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My_App"); //DON'T THINK THIS MATTERS
$client->setDeveloperKey('sdsfdfdddssffdfdfdfdn_dgdgs'); //GET AT AT DEVELOPERS.GOOGLE.COM
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

 $calendarId = 'test@test.com';

 $params = array(

'singleEvents' => true,
'orderBy' => 'startTime',
'timeMin' => date(DateTime::ATOM),//ONLY PULL EVENTS STARTING TODAY
  'maxResults' => 2 //ONLY USE THIS IF YOU WANT TO LIMIT THE NUMBER
              //OF EVENTS DISPLAYED

  );

 $events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params); 

foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {

    //Convert date to month and day

     $eventDateStr = $event->start->dateTime;
     if(empty($eventDateStr))
     {
         // it's an all day event
         $eventDateStr = $event->start->date;
     }

     $temp_timezone = $event->start->timeZone;

     if (!empty($temp_timezone)) {
     $timezone = new DateTimeZone($temp_timezone); //GET THE TIME ZONE
             //Set your default timezone in case your events don't have one
 } else { $timezone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Paris");
     }

     $eventdate = new DateTime($eventDateStr,$timezone);

     $newmonth = $eventdate->format("M");//CONVERT REGULAR EVENT DATE TO LEGIBLE MONTH
     $newday = $eventdate->format("j");//CONVERT REGULAR EVENT DATE TO LEGIBLE DAY

    ?>
    <div class="event-container">
    <div class="eventDate">
    <span class="month"><?php

    echo $newmonth;

     ?></span><br />
    <span class="day"><?php

    echo $newday;

     ?></span><span class="dayTrail"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="eventBody">
    <a href="<?php echo $event->htmlLink;
            //EVENT LINKS ARE STANDARDIZED, NO NEED TO ADD JUNK TO THE END
     ?>">

    <?php echo $event->summary; //SUMMARY = TITLE

    ?>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated 
Looking forward for response 
Thank you